# What does verb + くなる imply or mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs, subsidiary-verbs

I was talking to a person and they used:

> 大切にしたくなるよ。

Does that mean I have come to cherish or something like that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Does that mean I have come to cherish or something like that?

Yes, that is precisely the idea!

Now, a grammar explanation...

「なる」 here means "***to reach a certain (new) state***" and you will keep encountering this usage of the word as long as you study Japanese.  That is a promise from a native speaker.

> 「[連用形]{れんようけい} (continuative form) + なる」＝ "to become ~~", "to start doing ~~", etc.

「たく」 is the 連用形 of the subsidiary verb 「たい」("to want to"); therefore, 「～～したくなる」 means "to start wanting to ~~".  (「し」 is the 連用形 of「する」)

「[赤]{あか}くなる」 = "to turn red".  「赤く」 is the 連用形 of 「赤い」.

「パリに[行]{い}きたくなった。」 = "I have started wanting to go to Paris."

Comment: But since you need the verb form to end in い, how do you use this is non-past verbs? I assume this is correct:
りんごを食べたくなった (I started wanting to eat apples)
りんごを食べなくなった (I started not eating apples) (So, from now on, I'm not eating apples anymore)

My tries: (I started eating apples) (So, from now on, I'm eating apples)
りんごを食べになった。
りんごを食べるのようになった

Thanks!

Comment: @kuonb You don’t need the verb form to end in い; you need it to be the continuative stem (連用形) of the verb in question. The continuative _often_ ends in い, but not always. Monograde verbs like 食べる have continuatives that end in whatever vowel the stem of the root itself ends in (for 食べる, that’s _-e_: 食べ). So the corresponding form with 食べる is simply 食べ+なる. Whether 「りんごを食べなった」 is something any Japanese speaker would ever say is an entirely different matter, to which I don’t know the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Are you familiar with N + になる?  (To become N).  It's also done w/ verb forms & adjectives ending in い.  The い becomes く then add なる.

```
For adjectives:
大きい -> 大きくなる (Big -> Become Big)
狭い -> 狭くなる

Similarly, this can be done w/ verbs
したい -> したくなる (want to do - > become to want to do)
行きたい -> 行きたくなる (Want to go -> become to want to go)
```

Obviously the above are literal translations.  "Makes **_ want to _**" is usually better but needs context.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you
it's awkward translating it into English but the idea makes a lot of sense

Comment: "this can be done w/ **verbs**">> たい is not a verb, is it?

Comment: ~たい.  thought I made that clear with "verb forms".

Comment: @Baby Coder, hope it helped.  I knew I'd get down-voted, but it was too much for a reply.