# Strange form of ki ni naru

Tags: grammar

I am not able to understand the following use:

```
~がきにならなくなっていった
```

Does it mean I am/am not interested about the subject?
Can someone explain the conjugation used here please?

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28632/what-does-verb-%e3%81%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b-imply-or-mean

Comment: I do not think that conjugation applies here.This seems to be ならない + なる +  いる which seems strange - but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「～～が気{き}にならなくなっていった」

≒

> 「～～が気に + ならない + なる + いく」

The last part いった is from いく（行く） and not from いる like you stated in your comment above.  I am sure you know both いく and くる are often used as subsidiary verbs.  (The past tense form of いる is いた, and not いった.)

「気にならない」 means "***to not be concerned***", "***to be free from***", etc.

「なっていく」 means "***to (gradually) become***".  It expresses a ***shift from one state to the next***.

Old state: Concerned

↓

New state: Unconcerned

Thus,　「～～が気にならなくなっていった」 means:

> "(Someone) became less and less concerned about ~~ (over time)"

Comment: Why 行く part is in the past form? If it is "over time in the future", should non-past form have been used? Also, If it is "became from the moment in the past to the moment of the narration" should 来る have been used in this case? 「～～が気にならなくなってきた」?