# What difference does it make when we use 【なる】 in 「辞めたくなることがありますか」 or not?

Tags: grammar

Sentence A: 日本語が　難{むずか}しくて勉{べん}強{きょう}を　辞{や}めた**くなる**ことが　ありますか。

Sentence B:　日本語が　難{むずか}しくて勉{べん}強{きょう}を　辞{や}めたことが　ありますか。

What type of attribute does **なる** add to sentence A that is not exist in sentence B?

Comment: Does this post answer your question? [What does verb + くなる imply or mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28632/what-does-verb-%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B-imply-or-mean)

Comment: Thank you very much. I used to think that V-た in sentence A is related to た-form.
Now I understand that the whole story is something else!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 辞めた is just past tense:  *I quit (stopped) [studying]*.

However, 辞めたくなる is not past tense.  In fact this is

> 辞めたくなる = 辞めたい + なる

which means *I'm getting to want to quit [studying]*"

Now, if you just said,

> 辞めたい

then that's just *I want to quit*.